# Windows 10 cmd "Access is denied." error attempting to delete duplicate music files

Tags: windows-10, command-line, batch

I am attempting to delete redundant copies of WMA and M4A files in my iTunes media music folder, and I don't want to have to perform thousands of manual deletions. Each redundant copy has an appended parenthetical in its filename starting with a date, viz. "(2017_12_", so I am using the command

`del /s <<path>>*(2017_12*.*`

The cmd window returns each filename followed by "Access is denied." on the next line. I am running as administrator, I had just restarted, and nothing that obviously might have a hold on the files was running (I closed a couple of idle iTunes processes).

Is there something I can do to gain access to the files in the command line without a third-party application? Would a batch process, or something else native, allow me to do what the command line is not?

Comment: I accomplished the cleanup task by searching for (2017_12 in File Explorer, selecting all results, and deleting, but I would still like to know if it is possible to do from the command line.

Comment: You probably need to escape the `(` using `^(` instead.

Comment: Apparently not so, as the process identified thousands of files, just could not delete them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file is used by another process, or, if you do not have appropriate permission on it, it may cause problem when delete them.

Please open file **Properties** – **Security**, make sure that current user account has full permission on it.

Then, re-start system in **Clean Boot**, disable any 3rd party process at start up, or, you can also try to re-start system in **Safe Mode**, do not manually start any 3rd party process. Then, open **CMD** with admin permission and try the delete command again to check the result.

You may try command line as below:

**Cd** "*your folder location*"    //navigate to folder location

**Dir *.wma *.m4a**                //display all file with specific file type

**Del /s *2017_12*.***           //delete file which name includes 2017_12

**Dir *.wma *.m4a**                //display all file with specific file type and confirm that if specific file has been deleted

I had tried to delete *.txt* file which name including “*2017_12*” under location “*C:\New Folder*”:
[image]